# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in Spark Structured Streaming when sending Row.empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am a Kafka topic named `test` in which I am sending string messages. After that I am filtering those messages on the basis of some condition via Spark Structured Streaming. Like this:

```
scala> val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").option("subscribe", "test")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader = org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader@6ff87203

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val schema = StructType(StructField("message", StringType) :: Nil)
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(message,StringType,true))

scala> val data = df.load().select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).as("value"))
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: struct<message: string>]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

scala> implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = class[message[0]: string]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> val q = data.select("value.*").map(row => if(row.getString(0) == "hello") row else Row.empty)
q: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [message: string]

scala> q.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@7ef3b7ac
```

But as soon as I send the message failing the condition, i.e., `{"message":"he"}`, it gives me following error:

```
scala> -------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
17/06/10 12:07:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/06/10 12:07:10 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17/06/10 12:07:10 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
17/06/10 12:07:10 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = c6d64268-e8a4-4171-abb5-84ea7696833c, runId = 809b5544-7d91-4528-8ea0-05239d2690f7] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1491)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1491)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:819)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1719)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1674)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1663)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2019)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2040)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2084)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2820)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2804)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2803)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSink.addBatch(console.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:650)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:650)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:650)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:649)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:202)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.isNullAt(Row.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.isNullAt(rows.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:320)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I cannot understand why I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception here. If the data is empty then I should get an empty `DataFrame/Dataset`, not an exception.

Is this an expected behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is `Row.empty` means a row with no columns. In your codes, you told Spark the row schema is `StructType(StructField("message", StringType) :: Nil)`, so you should not return `Row.empty`. Instead, you should return `Row(null)` which is a row that has a `null` column.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just sharing in case someone finds it useful.

If your dataframe does not have all the columns which are there in the schema then it will throw this error.

rows.scala ->

```
override def get(i: Int): Any = values(i)
```

The `i` is the index of current field from the schema. You are trying to get `i`th field from the row, but it does not have it, hence the exception.

Just adding a value (could be null as well if the schema allows it) for that schema attribute will fix the issue.